# How to write a generic LINQ query for filtering of data based on first name middle name and last name

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have one table which contains employees records like first , middle, last name. I have 3 textboxes for entering all these.
Now on .net side I want to write a single LINQ query to filter data based on `first name middle name and last name`. Any of these 3 fields can be blank.
Is these any way to write a single generic LINQ query?

Answer (score 4):

```
public IList<Employee> GetEmployees(string first, string middle, string last)
{
    var query = context.Employees.AsQueryable();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(first))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName == first);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(middle))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.MiddleName == middle);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(last))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.LastName == last);
    }

    return query.Select(x => 
                    new Employee 
                    { 
                        FullName = string.Join(" ", new string[] { x.FirstName, x.MiddleName, x.LastName}.Where(y => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y)))
                    })
                .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write one linq query with or condition like bellow

> _context.tablename.where(p=>p.firstName.contains(txtFirstName) || p.middleName.contains(txtMiddleName) || p.lastName.contains(txtLastName)).ToList();

Change `tablename` with you database table in above linq query

Answer (score 0):

when iterating just verify if the criteria in use has value

```
var criteria = new 
{
    FirstName = default(string),
    MiddleName = default(string),
    LastName = "Doe",
};

var query = from record in Context()
            where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.FirstName) 
                    && record.FirstName == criteria.FirstName
                || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.MiddleName) 
                    && record.MiddleName == criteria.MiddleName
                || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.LastName) 
                    && record.LastName == criteria.LastName
            select record;
```

Comment: check gist for fully working example https://gist.github.com/dandohotaru/d0598c7dd9599cc4e173b478d7e4cf82

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that;

```
    public List<Employee> RetrieveEmployees(string firstName, string lastName, string middleName)
    {
        var query = from employees in context.Employees
            where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) || employees.FirstName == firstName) &&
                  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) || employees.LastName == lastName) &&
                  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName) || employees.MiddleName == middleName)
        select employees;

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: This is not about understanding, it is about evaluation order. In C# `&&` is evaluated before `||`, and SQL does the same: `AND` is evaluated before `OR`. You basically wrote `C1 OR (C2 AND C3) OR (C4 AND C5) OR C6` (and these braces are really only there for understanding)

Comment: Not anymore because you fixed it, I was just trying to explain why it needed fixing. I hope you understand!